# getaddrinfo - возвращаемые данные об IP адресе

Tags: winapi, winsock

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот делаю вызов функции getaddinfo из Winsock:

```
char my_char_HOST[] = "ru.stackoverflow.com";
    char my_char_NAME_SERVICE[] = "https";
 
    ADDRINFOA my_ADDRINFOA;
 
    memset(&my_ADDRINFOA, 0, sizeof(my_ADDRINFOA)); 
    my_ADDRINFOA.ai_family = AF_INET;     
    my_ADDRINFOA.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 

 
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;  // Сюда getaddrinfo - заносит возвращенную информацию
 
    INT my_getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo(my_char_HOST, my_char_NAME_SERVICE, &my_ADDRINFOA, &servinfo);
 
    cout << "my_getaddrinfo:" << my_getaddrinfo<< endl;   //Равно 0 - завершается успешно
```

Все работает, getaddrinfo завершается без ошибок, вывожу на консоль заполненные функцией данные об IP в указателе на структуру servinfo(sockaddr) в параметре sa_data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    cout << "ai_addr_sa_data:" << (int)(servinfo->ai_addr->sa_data[i]) << endl;
}
```

Вот что выводится:

```
ai_addr_sa_data:1       //?
ai_addr_sa_data:-69     //?
ai_addr_sa_data:-105    //(это переполненный char числа 151)
ai_addr_sa_data:101
ai_addr_sa_data:-127    //(это переполненный char числа 193)
ai_addr_sa_data:69
```

IP адрес ru.stackoverflow.com - 151.101.193.69, то есть getaddrinfo правильно вернула значение, но вопрос, что за значения в первых двух байтах - 1 и -69 ??? Причем они всегда постоянны, то есть чтобы я не запрашивал - google, facebook, mail или stackoverflow - первые два байта возвращаются именно с этими значениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sockaddr указывает на структуру sockaddr_in,в которой первые два байта - это номер порта. Так что если вы воспользуетесь этой структурой, вы увидите там 443, записанное в сетевом порядке байт.

Comment: gbg,                                                                                                                                                                                   struct sockaddr {
        ushort  sa_family;
        char    sa_data[14];
};                                                                                                                                                                                      я обращаюсь ведь именно к элементу sa_data, а не sa_familyю

Comment: Потому что функция "универсальная". Когда речь идет о протоколе IP, надо перегонять ее в sockaddr_in.

Comment: gbg, да Вы правы. Только за место 443 порта, я там наблюдаю 47873 порт. ... а похоже 47873 число получается, потому что getaddrinfo возвращает в число в "сетевом" порядке байт.

Comment: Не "похоже", а так и есть, я же писал об этом в ответе. Все эти функции все что длиннее байта принимают и отдают только в сетевом порядке.

Comment: gbg, а еще прям один вопрос: это что касается ip адресов ipv4, а что, если имени хоста будет соответствовать ip адрес в формате ipv6 ? ipv6 адресс состоит из 8 "частей" по 2 байта - это 16 байт, но в структуре sockaddr под параметр sa_data - отведено всего 14 байт и то первые два байта это sin_port из структуры sockaddr_in. Или в этом случае будет задействован "хвост" sin_zero[8] из структуры sockaddr_in ?

Comment: Конвертировать нужно будет вот в это https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/ws2ipdef/ns-ws2ipdef-sockaddr_in6_w2ksp1 Сами смотрите, что на что там наложится.